# Firestore get all all documents from a sub collection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing a feature that allows users to view current posts they interacted with. To go about this in my user's document I have created a sub collection called "current" and inside is a document containing the name of the posts document

I also have a recycler view setup on a fragment to be able to display the current posts

Where I am stuck is I need to be able to get all of the posts document ids from the user's current collection and retrieve the associated posts from the posts collection. I am not sure if this is possible

[image]

Comment: It's possible. what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: how to retrieve all of the strings from the documents in "current" collection and store them so they can then be retrieved

Comment: What is the expected result and what have you tried so far in code?